# Finding out the value of rate constant on titration

Tags: kinetics

The question goes as follows

Consider the reaction $$\ce{X(aq) \longrightarrow Y(aq) + Z(aq)}$$

The above reaction is titrated with a reagent $A$ and all of $X, Y, Z$ reacts with $A$ with the ratio of 'n' factors of $X, Y, Z=1:2:3$

here n factor refers to change in oxidation number of substance per mole of the substance on titration with $A$

The following data was obtained.

[image]

The question is to find out the value of rate constant considering the titration reaction to be first order.

The value of rate constant is given by $\frac{0. 693}{t_{1/2}}$ So I have to find out half life of the reaction . I am facing trouble finding out since the rate of voume of A required depends on the amount of substance present at that instant. Any help shall be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From a mole balance, we find $C = n_x(t) + n_y(t) + n_z(t) = n_x(t) + 2n_y(t)$, where the second equality follows from the stoichiometry of the reaction. In particular, our boundary conditions are $C = n_x(0) = 2n_y(\infty).$

We assume that the reaction is first-order, so $n_x(t) = n_x(0)\exp(-kt) = C\exp(-kt).$ The two measurements give us the set of equations 
\begin{align*} 
80D &= n_x(5) + 5n_y(5) &&= C\exp(-5k) + \frac{5}{2}C(1-\exp(-5k)) \\
100D &= 5n_y(\infty) &&= \frac{5}{2}C,
\end{align*}
where $D$ is an undetermined proportionality constant for the titration, and the coefficient of 5 in $n_y$ accounts for the fact that 2 equivalents of $A$ react with $n_y$ and 3 equivalents with $n_z$. Dividing one equation by the other produces the final result $$\frac{4}{5} = \frac{2}{5}\exp(-5k)+1-\exp(-5k),$$ which can be solved for $k$ and hence $t_{1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a tricky problem, and I'm not sure I have it all. The amounts of $X,Y, Z$ at time $t$ are $X=X_0\exp(-kt), ~Y=X_0(1-\exp(-kt)), ~ Z=X_0(1-\exp(-kt))$ and the measurement is  volume A. At infinite time $X_\infty=0$ and so using the ratios given $2Y_\infty+3Z_\infty=5\cdot 100$ is equivalent to $2X_0$ (by adding up $X,Y,Z$ at $t=\infty$) and at $t=5, $ $X_5+2Y_5+3Z_5=6\cdot80$ is equivalent to $X_0(2-\exp(-5k))$ so you should have all that you need if you now take ratios as $(500/480)=2X_0/(X_0(2-\exp(-5k)))$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I didn't get how you equated the number of equivalents of $Y$ and $Z$ with volume of reagent used. Can you please explain.

Comment: I'll try, I assumed that the ratios 1:2:3 are of volume. Then at infinity 100 ml is made of  5 parts of which 2 are Y and 3 Z , and at 5 sec there are 6 parts, 1 X, 2Y and 3Z.

Comment: no the ratios are n factors.for example the n factor of $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ is $6$ according to the reaction $$\ce{Cr2O7^{2-} + 14H+ +  6e- => 2Cr^{3+} + 7H2O}$$ because 6 $e-$ are involved.

Comment: I assumed it was but then I don't see how you can answer the question as you don't know how much A is used for each of X, Y and Z . Thus I had to assume that if n=3 for Z then 3 times as much A is used than for X.